# Count rows in second table with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have a query where I output some results

```
SELECT
    t1.busName,
    t1.busCity,
    COUNT(t2.ofr_id) AS cntOffers
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t2.ofr_busID = t1.busID)
```

The query above returns only one row, however, if I remove COUNT and leave only below query I get multiple results. What am I missing? And how can I fetch results from the first table while getting associated results count from t2?

```
SELECT
    t1.busName,
    t1.busCity
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t2.ofr_busID = t1.busID)
```

Comment: Add `GROUP BY t1.busName,
    t1.busCity` in the first query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `group by`:

```
SELECT t1.busName, t1.busCity,
       COUNT(t2.ofr_id) AS cntOffers
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN
     t2
     ON t2.ofr_busID = t1.busID
GROUP BY t1.busName, t1.busCity;
```

Most databases would return an error on your version of the query, because you have unaggregated and aggregated columns in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Oh, I need to GROUP BY each column from t1?

Comment: @santa . . . It is a good idea to include all the non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` -- unless you really, really, really know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

It actually seems that the `COUNT()` in your first query is forcing a `GROUP BY` (because of the aggregation) on that field, which explains why you get only one row, but that does not imply that you only have one row in it.

Check out this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7776/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TestData (a int, b int);

INSERT INTO TestData
    (a, b)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 3);
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT a, count(b) from TestData
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7776/2/0)**:

```
| a | count(b) |
|---|----------|
| 1 |        3 |
```

As Gordon Linoff suggested, you need to use `GROUP BY` explicitly in order to replicate the same behavior without the `COUNT`.